# Object Solve option not avaliable

Tags: tracking

I'm trying to do **object tracking** using Blender 2.71. In a youtube video the guy simply clicks "Object Motion" in the Solve tab.

His Screen:

[image: His Screen]

My screen:

[image]

But I can't find this option.

[image: My Screen]

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, motion tracking is set up to **solve camera motion**.

[image]

To enable **object solving** mode you need to click on the plus sign of the Objects Tab on the right side of the screen (if it's not visible press <kbd>N</kbd>)

[image]

and select **Object**.

[image]

Now **Solve Object Motion** is enabled.

[image]