# 'object' option not available in Object Solver panel

Tags: objects, tracking

I'm following a tutorial on object tracking and when I try to object solve the cube the "object" option doesn't appear in the drop down menu of the "object" field. What have I missed?[image]

Comment: It's hard to tell what's going on without looking at your file. Could you please upload your .blend file here?

Comment: possibly related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15741/object-solve-option-not-avaliable/15743#15743

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what tutorial you are following, but I think you might have missed something. The modifier is on the cube, but the cube is the object you are trying to track to is what it sounds like. You can't use the object which is being modified as the target object in any field, in any modifier. The tutor might have duplicated the object, or done something without proper narration, but as far as I know the target object can never be the object being modified.

Answer (score 0):

Untick "Active Clip" and you'll get a drop-down containing all the available tracking clips. Select the clip relating to the object you tracked and it should then be available.