# How to track object in shot with static camera

Tags: tracking

After putting trackers on an object, I am unable to "Setup Tracking Scene" without trackers on the Camera as well.   How can I solve for the object only, in situations where there is no camera movement?

Comment: If the camera doesn move you need to use tripod solve. Note that there is no way to get 3d information out of a tirpod solve.

Comment: If you want to solve the object only: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15741/object-solve-option-not-avaliable and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19638/motion-tracking-round-objects/19712#19712